# SKStoreproductviewcontroller truncated in landscape mode

Tags: iphone, ios, uiviewcontroller, storekit

I've just added SKStoreProductViewController and presented it from my own UIViewController.
If I rotate device to landscape mode - only header fits the width, other parts are truncated

```
....
NSDictionary *parameters = @{SKStoreProductParameterITunesItemIdentifier:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:[productID integerValue]]};

    [self.storeViewController loadProductWithParameters:parameters
                                   completionBlock:^(BOOL result, NSError *error) {
                                       if (result)
                                       {
                                           [presentingViewController presentModalViewController:self.storeViewController
                                                                                       animated:YES];
                                       }
                                       handler(result);
                                   }];
```

[image]

[image]

Is it possible to adapt "product page" in landscape mode, to make it looks good?

Env: iPhone 4S IOS 6.0.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's very poorly implemented.
I'm actually surprised that this has managed to pass any QA whatsoever on Apple's part.

When you press on one of the screenshots, it displays a, let's say, "detail" screen, where the scroll view still cuts off the images and the images themselves aren't centered on the screen, which leads to them being half obscured.

I've logged a bug in Apple's bug reporting system and I encourage you to do the same, as that'll increase the chance that Apple actually fixes it.

https://developer.apple.com/bugreporter/

Comment: iOS 7 StoreProductViewController supports portrait only